# I can't access the demo accounts provided on the thingsboard website

Tags: thingsboard

I completed the set up for thingsboard using Installing Thingsboard on Windows (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/) everything has started to function. But I cant access the demo accounts.
It is continously showing Authentication Failed.

If I try any of the credentials except sysadmin(https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/demo-account/).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Just for clarification: Login as a sysadmin works for you and login as tenant or customer does not work?

Comment: I have this issue too. Demo accounts are all good, except the sysadmin. If I login using sysadmin@thingsboard.org / sysadmin, it shows Authentication Failed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the demo data as described in the [installation guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/#thingsboard-service-installation) ?

The demo accounts will only exist if the demo data was installed.